# Model divergence in a pytorch TD3 implementation converted to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

Based on this [implementation](https://github.com/sfujim/TD3) of [TD3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09477.pdf), I converted different torch-based methods to their tensorflow equivalents. No matter what hyperparameters I use, torch's version will start converging by 50,000 - 100,000 steps which happens within a few minutes of starting the training. However, tensorflow version doesn't show any signs of improvement up to 600,000 steps. Here's a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gG434fkNOQKXU3-TNOUBA04-44BE7H0Q?usp=sharing) with both versions and I will include here the converted methods. I'm using gym's [BipedalWalker-v3](https://elegantrl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/BipedalWalker-v3.html) environment for both versions.

**What I tried**

I tried everything from lowering the default learning rate of the paper `0.0003`, hidden unit sizes (i tried 64, 128, 256, 512 and even 400, 300 the paper's defaults nothing works), changed batch size (100, 128, 256, ...), lowered buffer size (default: 1,000,000) to 100,000, 50,000 ... I also tried reusing `tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)` and doing the updates using the same tape, tried using [tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage) instead of manual averaging and needless to say, I even re-wrote the code multiple times. NOTHING works.

**Note**

`self.max_action` in torch's implementation, equals 1 and you will find it hardcoded in tf's, to clear any confusion you may have.

**Common hyperparameters**

- dense units: 256 (different from paper's 400 and 300)
- actor update delay: 2
- exploration noise std: 0.1
- policy noise std: 0.2
- noise clip norm: 0.5
- tau: 0.005
- optimizer: adam
- learning rate: 0.0003
- replay buffer size: 1,000,000
- replay initial size: 25,000
- batch size: 256 (different from paper's 100)

**Torch actor and critic models**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Actor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, max_action):
        super(Actor, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(state_dim, 256)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(256, action_dim)
        self.max_action = max_action

    def forward(self, state):
        a = F.relu(self.l1(state))
        a = F.relu(self.l2(a))
        return self.max_action * torch.tanh(self.l3(a))


class Critic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim):
        super(Critic, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(state_dim + action_dim, 256)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(256, 1)
        self.l4 = nn.Linear(state_dim + action_dim, 256)
        self.l5 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.l6 = nn.Linear(256, 1)

    def forward(self, state, action):
        sa = torch.cat([state, action], 1)
        q1 = F.relu(self.l1(sa))
        q1 = F.relu(self.l2(q1))
        q1 = self.l3(q1)
        q2 = F.relu(self.l4(sa))
        q2 = F.relu(self.l5(q2))
        q2 = self.l6(q2)
        return q1, q2

    def Q1(self, state, action):
        sa = torch.cat([state, action], 1)
        q1 = F.relu(self.l1(sa))
        q1 = F.relu(self.l2(q1))
        q1 = self.l3(q1)
        return q1
```

**Tensorflow actor and critic models**

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input



def actor(input_shape, output_units):
    x0 = Input(input_shape)
    x = Dense(256, 'relu')(x0)
    x = Dense(256, 'relu')(x)
    output = Dense(output_units, 'tanh')(x)
    return Model(x0, output)


def critic(input_shape):
    x0 = Input(input_shape)
    x1 = Dense(256, 'relu')(x0)
    x1 = Dense(256, 'relu')(x1)
    v1 = Dense(1)(x1)
    x2 = Dense(256, 'relu')(x0)
    x2 = Dense(256, 'relu')(x2)
    v2 = Dense(1)(x2)
    return Model(x0, [v1, v2])
```

**Torch train step**

```
def train(self, replay_buffer, batch_size=256):
    self.total_it += 1
    state, action, next_state, reward, not_done = replay_buffer.sample(batch_size)
    with torch.no_grad():
        noise = (torch.randn_like(action) * self.policy_noise).clamp(
            -self.noise_clip, self.noise_clip
        )
        next_action = (self.actor_target(next_state) + noise).clamp(
            -self.max_action, self.max_action
        )
        target_Q1, target_Q2 = self.critic_target(next_state, next_action)
        target_Q = torch.min(target_Q1, target_Q2)
        target_Q = reward + not_done * self.discount * target_Q
    current_Q1, current_Q2 = self.critic(state, action)
    critic_loss = F.mse_loss(current_Q1, target_Q) + F.mse_loss(
        current_Q2, target_Q
    )
    self.critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
    critic_loss.backward()
    self.critic_optimizer.step()
    if self.total_it % self.policy_freq == 0:
        actor_loss = -self.critic.Q1(state, self.actor(state)).mean()
        self.actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward()
        self.actor_optimizer.step()
        for param, target_param in zip(
            self.critic.parameters(), self.critic_target.parameters()
        ):
            target_param.data.copy_(
                self.tau * param.data + (1 - self.tau) * target_param.data
            )
        for param, target_param in zip(
            self.actor.parameters(), self.actor_target.parameters()
        ):
            target_param.data.copy_(
                self.tau * param.data + (1 - self.tau) * target_param.data
            )
```

**tensorflow training methods**

```
def update_critic_weights(self, states, actions, rewards, dones, new_states):
    policy_noise = tf.random.normal(
        (self.n_envs * self.buffer_batch_size, self.n_actions),
        0,
        self.policy_noise_std,
    )
    policy_noise = tf.clip_by_value(policy_noise, -self.noise_clip, self.noise_clip)
    target_actions = tf.clip_by_value(
        self.target_actor(new_states) + policy_noise, -1, 1
    )
    target_value1, target_value2 = self.target_critic(
        tf.concat([new_states, target_actions], 1)
    )
    target_value = rewards + (1 - dones) * self.gamma * tf.minimum(
        target_value1, target_value2
    )
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        value1, value2 = self.critic(tf.concat([states, actions], 1))
        value_loss = MSE(value1, target_value) + MSE(value2, target_value2)
    self.critic.optimizer.minimize(
        value_loss, self.critic.trainable_variables, tape=tape
    )

def update_actor_weights(self, states):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        actions = self.actor(states)
        loss = -tf.reduce_mean(self.critic([tf.concat([states, actions], 1)])[0])
    self.actor.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.actor.trainable_variables, tape=tape)

@tf.function
def train_step(self):
    self.updates.assign_add(1)
    step_actions = self.actor(self.get_states())
    exploration_noise = tf.random.normal(
        [self.n_actions], 0, self.exploration_noise_std
    )
    step_actions = tf.clip_by_value(step_actions + exploration_noise, -1, 1)
    tf.numpy_function(self.step_envs, [step_actions, False, True], [])
    batch = tf.numpy_function(self.concat_buffer_samples, [], 5 * [tf.float32])
    self.update_critic_weights(*batch)
    if tf.math.equal(tf.math.mod(self.updates, self.actor_delay), 0):
        self.update_actor_weights(batch[0])
        self.sync_target_models()

def sync_target_models(self):
    for model, target_model in self.model_groups:
        for var, target_var in zip(
            model.trainable_variables, target_model.trainable_variables
        ):
            target_var.assign(self.tau * var + (1 - self.tau) * target_var)
```

The results which you can reproduce using the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gG434fkNOQKXU3-TNOUBA04-44BE7H0Q?usp=sharing):

**Torch**

```
time: 0:00:01.928306, steps: 3875, games: 10, fps: 2009.0, mean reward: -105.27, best reward: -82.24
time: 0:00:06.234093, steps: 13832, games: 20, fps: 2312.0, mean reward: -99.73, best reward: -77.94
time: 0:00:09.219966, steps: 20691, games: 30, fps: 2297.0, mean reward: -99.37, best reward: -75.26
time: 0:00:24.854520, steps: 27736, games: 40, fps: 450.0, mean reward: -102.14, best reward: -65.01
time: 0:00:28.400598, steps: 28444, games: 50, fps: 199.0, mean reward: -103.27, best reward: -65.01
time: 0:01:24.811760, steps: 39761, games: 60, fps: 200.0, mean reward: -107.92, best reward: -65.01
time: 0:02:23.950100, steps: 51719, games: 70, fps: 202.0, mean reward: -105.17, best reward: -65.01
time: 0:03:29.150313, steps: 64853, games: 80, fps: 201.0, mean reward: -103.09, best reward: -65.01
time: 0:04:27.118459, steps: 76666, games: 90, fps: 203.0, mean reward: -105.1, best reward: -65.01
time: 0:05:33.525320, steps: 90105, games: 100, fps: 202.0, mean reward: -104.47, best reward: -31.01
time: 0:06:38.586421, steps: 103162, games: 110, fps: 200.0, mean reward: -102.21, best reward: -31.01
time: 0:07:50.672645, steps: 117707, games: 120, fps: 201.0, mean reward: -99.69, best reward: -31.01
time: 0:09:10.076208, steps: 133707, games: 130, fps: 201.0, mean reward: -93.53, best reward: -31.01
time: 0:10:07.278960, steps: 145180, games: 140, fps: 200.0, mean reward: -88.81, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:11:04.842319, steps: 156767, games: 150, fps: 201.0, mean reward: -85.12, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:11:30.127616, steps: 161788, games: 160, fps: 198.0, mean reward: -83.37, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:11:34.950709, steps: 162755, games: 170, fps: 200.0, mean reward: -86.65, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:12:06.615783, steps: 169146, games: 180, fps: 201.0, mean reward: -89.97, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:13:11.028382, steps: 182064, games: 190, fps: 200.0, mean reward: -84.38, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:14:30.357974, steps: 198064, games: 200, fps: 201.0, mean reward: -79.24, best reward: -30.43
time: 0:15:49.531968, steps: 214064, games: 210, fps: 202.0, mean reward: -74.81, best reward: -27.15
time: 0:17:01.859939, steps: 228590, games: 220, fps: 200.0, mean reward: -71.18, best reward: 37.19
```

Tensorflow:

```
time: 0:00:33.882932, steps: 6825, games: 10, fps: 206, mean reward: -81.9, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:01:30.612159, steps: 18306, games: 20, fps: 201, mean reward: -77.51, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:01:49.359029, steps: 22075, games: 30, fps: 190, mean reward: -88.67, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:01:53.394437, steps: 22881, games: 40, fps: 190, mean reward: -94.84, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:01:56.996669, steps: 23603, games: 50, fps: 205, mean reward: -98.51, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:02:16.071768, steps: 27402, games: 60, fps: 192, mean reward: -97.91, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:02:28.969803, steps: 29996, games: 70, fps: 204, mean reward: -100.71, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:02:32.286386, steps: 30656, games: 80, fps: 203, mean reward: -102.14, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:02:41.094522, steps: 32407, games: 90, fps: 198, mean reward: -103.45, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:02:57.489013, steps: 35634, games: 100, fps: 171, mean reward: -104.67, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:03:15.559559, steps: 39184, games: 110, fps: 199, mean reward: -109.12, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:03:26.770144, steps: 41374, games: 120, fps: 194, mean reward: -113.48, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:03:56.878539, steps: 47205, games: 130, fps: 195, mean reward: -114.48, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:04:37.541307, steps: 55078, games: 140, fps: 194, mean reward: -116.36, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:05:14.164399, steps: 62089, games: 150, fps: 192, mean reward: -115.31, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:06:14.816104, steps: 73559, games: 160, fps: 197, mean reward: -118.41, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:06:51.555758, steps: 80434, games: 170, fps: 185, mean reward: -118.5, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:07:11.885412, steps: 84218, games: 180, fps: 188, mean reward: -118.14, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:07:51.662705, steps: 91584, games: 190, fps: 184, mean reward: -119.91, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:08:12.492280, steps: 95425, games: 200, fps: 181, mean reward: -119.18, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:08:33.173622, steps: 99274, games: 210, fps: 186, mean reward: -117.43, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:08:40.747114, steps: 100642, games: 220, fps: 189, mean reward: -116.43, best reward: -68.04
time: 0:09:09.865704, steps: 105968, games: 230, fps: 185, mean reward: -116.34, best reward: -68.04
```

And it will keep diverging forever guaranteed, I almost reached 1,000,000 steps and the reward keeps circling around the same average.